# Shared element transition from recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

Lets say I have `FragmentA` and `DetailActivity`. `FragmentA` has a `RecyclerViewAdapter`. The items in that adapter all have an image. When a user clicks on an item I want to show a detail page where that same image is shown (in `DetailActivity`). So I made that image a shared element, so we get a nice transition when navigating to the `DetailActivity`. I've implemented this with this code:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
  (Activity) context,
  recyclerViewHolder.img_bridge_icon,
  ViewCompat.getTransitionName(recyclerViewHolder.img_bridge_icon));

ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, options.toBundle());
```

This is working great! The image gets scaled and re-positioned. Now, when I return to `FragmentA`, the item in the adapter already has the image loaded while the shared element is still busy with its transition. This means that the shared element is shown twice until the transition animation is done.

I know that this happens because `FragmentA` has to create its view again when returning from `DetailActivity`. But how can I solve this? The adapter should somehow know not to show the shared `ImageView` when the transition is loading.

I've added a screenshot that was made in the middle of the transition from `DetailActivity` to `FragmentA`. The bottom image is the one from the `DetailActivity`, the top one is from the item in the adapter, which should not be there (the bottom one should be the only one, because that's the one in the transition).

[image: Image double shared element]

Comment: Refer this: https://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/

Comment: Thats for activity to activity and fragment to fragment. What I need is from fragment to activity.